# Memory leak in Bundle.main.loadNibNamed

Tags: swift, memory-leaks

I have strange **memory leak** in my class `BottomTabView`.
I have `class func` for load it class instance from `xib` by `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed`

```
@objc class func loadFromNib() -> BottomTabView? {
    if let topLevelObjects = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BottomTabView", owner: nil, options: nil) { // <<< this is a memory leak
        if topLevelObjects.count > 0 {
            let view = topLevelObjects[0] as? BottomTabView
            if let view = view {
                var rect = view.frame
                rect.size.height = BottomTabView.Height
                view.frame = rect

                view.shiftConstraint?.constant = BottomTabView.Shift
            }
            return view
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

[instrument screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RQnS.png)

how is I can fix it? I don't understand what holds it.

Comment: You should also include the implementation of `loadNibNamed` in your question. Unrelated to your question, but you could merge the outer 3 if statements into a single one like `if let bottomTabView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BottomTabView", owner: nil, options: nil).first as? BottomTabView {`

Comment: There's nothing here that can cause a memory leak, unless you did a hack like overriding `loadNibNamed` in an extension

Comment: “I don't understand what holds it.” If there’s really a leak, both the memory graph and Instruments will show you, drawing the retain cycle as a diagram.

Comment: implementation of `loadNibNamed` - is standard method `UINib`